# Modificar una respuesta de MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy trabajando con un modelo de Mongoose, este es el modelo

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import UserModel from '../../../models/user.model'
import { error500 } from '../../../global/errors'
import AreaModel from '../../../models/area.model'


const UserChangesRoute = Router()


UserChangesRoute.get( '/:id', ( req: Request, res: Response ) => {

    const id: String = req.params.id
    const pop_user  = { path: 'modification.user', select: 'name last_name' }
    UserModel.find( { _id: id }, 'modification' ).sort({ 'modification.date': 1 })
    .populate( pop_user )
    .lean()
    .exec( ( err: any, data: any ) => {
        if( err ) {
            return res.status( 500 ).json( { message: error500, err } )
        }
        // I used to: data = data.toObject()
        for( let i = 0; i < data[0].modification.length; i++ ) {

            if( data[0].modification[ i ][ 'updated' ][ 0 ] === 'area' ) {
                AreaModel.findById( data[0].modification[ i ][ 'updated' ][ 1 ], 'name', ( e: any, area: any ) => {
                    if( !e ) data[0].modification[ i ][ 'updated' ][ 1 ] = area.name
                });

                AreaModel.findById( data[0].modification[ i ][ 'updated' ][ 2 ], 'name', ( e: any, area: any ) => {
                    if( !e ) data[0].modification[ i ][ 'updated' ][ 2 ] = area.name
                });
            }
        }
        res.status( 200 ).json( { data } )
    })
})


export default UserChangesRoute
```

Estoy intentando buscar y reemplazar partes del arreglo donde viene `data[0].modification` Aquí adentro de almacena algo así

```
[ 'area', '5d144642416ada46385d01b8', '5d144681416ada46385d01b9', 'Área'];
```

Debería de quedar así al final

```
['area', 'Sistemas', 'Recursos Humanos', 'Área'];
```

El índice 1, indica a nivel de estructura de DB, que se movió en el front. El segundo índice es, qué área (en este caso) se quitó, el tercer índice es por qué área se reemplazó y el último, es únicamente un tag para el front.

> Es un historial de cambios.

Lo que estoy intentando es, reemplazar esos id de Mongo por el nombre del área, intenté hacerlo con un `populate`, sin embargo no es un arreglo de `Schemas` y pues no tiene la referencia al modelo de Areas, reitero es un historial de cambios, no solo se guardan áreas, si no roles, nombres, jefes directos, en fin... todo lo que se cambie en el front, debe ser almacenado en esa forma, y cada cambio es un `$push` al arreglo de `modifications`

Ahora, el problema es que Mongoose, me retorna un `MongoDocument`, no un `JSON` (Por más parecido que sea) Necesito hacer el parsing de ese `MongoDocument` a `JSON` para poder trabajarlo.

Este es el modelo de Usuario ( Pedido por Mauricio Contreras )

```
import mongos from 'mongoose'
import validator from 'mongoose-unique-validator'


const schema = new mongos.Schema({

    name: { 
        type      : String, 
        required  : [ true, 'El nombre es necesario' ], 
        maxlength : [ 50, 'El nombre no puede exceder los 50 caracteres'],
        minlength : [ 3, 'El nombre debe contener 3 o más caracteres'] 
    },
    last_name:  { 
        type      : String, 
        required  : [ true, 'El apellido es necesario' ], 
        maxlength : [ 100, 'El apellido no puede exceder los 50 caracteres'],
        minlength : [ 3, 'El apellido debe contener 3 o más caracteres'],
    },
    user_name:  { 
        type: String, 
        unique    : [ true, 'El usuario está duplicado' ], 
        required  : [ true, 'El usuario es necesario' ], 
        maxlength : [ 25, 'El usuario no puede exceder los 25 caracteres'] },
    email: { 
        type      : String, 
        unique    : [ true, 'El correo está duplicado'], 
        required  : [ true, 'El correo es necesario' ], 
        maxlength : [ 100, 'El correo no puede exceder los 100 caracteres'],
        match     : [/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                    'El correo electrónico no tiene el formato adecuado'] },
    gender        : { type: Number, min: 0, max: 2 },
    photo         : { type: String },
    phone         : { type: String },

    role          : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role' },
    area          : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Area'  },
    boss          : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'  },
    permissions: [{
        module    : { type: mongos.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Module' },
        chmod     :  { type: String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 5, default: 'r' }
    }],

    password      :   { type: String },
    status        :   { type: String, default: 'active' },
    last_login    :   { type: Date },
    addedBy       :   { type: String },
    addedDate     : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    modification  : [{
        _id       : false,
        user      : { type: mongos.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        date      : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        updated   : { type: Array }
    }]

}, { collection: 'users' })

schema.plugin( validator, {  message: 'Ya existe el correo o ID {VALUE} en la base de datos' } )

const UserModel = mongos.model('User', schema )

export default UserModel
```

Intenté utilizar el método [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) Pero no me está resultando.

De igual forma usé [toObject()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) Pero me dice es no es una función.

**¿Cómo puedo reemplazar los datos de un MongoDocument?**

Comment: No entiendo eso de crear una variable. Los modifico por que necesito ambos nombres, el anterior y el que reemplazó al valor anterior

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo de tu documento tipo `User`? Gracias

Comment: No entiendo que relevancia tiene que ver  el User, pero lo agrego.

Comment: La relevancia es saber exactamente la estructura del campo `modification`, en tu pregunta no quedaba totalmente claro, ahora que la veo puedo trabajar en una solución.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**

## RESPUESTA CORTA

Puedes lograr lo que te propones usando un método de agregación, trataré de explicarte esto con el mayor detalle posible. Pero será una explicación bastante larga.

> ***Nota***: El método aquí expuesto funciona en MongoDB 4.0 o superior.

Usaré un método de agregación, el cual irá realizando la tarea por etapas, hasta lograr el resultado deseado. Puedes leer más sobre [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/index.html) en la documentación de [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/).

Usando como modelo los datos proporcionados en tu pregunta, vamos a escribir un método de agregación que ejecutaremos cuando se realice la solicitud de *cambios realizados* sobre un usuario, tal como lo tienes en tu ruta.

Una de las diferencias principales a la hora de usar la API de agregación, es que la misma devolverá un `Array` que contiene documentos JSON simples, los cuales podrás luego modificar si aún te hiciera falta. En cambio las consultas ([`Queries`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)) realizadas sobre el modelo, devuelven una instancia del modelo (un [documento de Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) en este caso), y como tal sus métodos y propiedades.

**Usando Agregación:**

```
const id:String = req.params.id;

// CREAMOS la agregación:
// la llameré aggregateByArea porque la misma realizará un $lookup sobre la colección 'areas'

const aggregateByArea = UserModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
          _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        modification: {
          $map: {
            input: '$modification',
            as: 'mod',
            in: {
              'user': '$$mod.user',
              'date': '$$mod.date',
              'updated': {
                $map: {
                  input: '$$mod.updated',
                  as: 'item',
                  in: {
                    $convert: {
                      input: '$$item',
                      to: 'objectId',
                      onError: '$$item'
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$modification'},
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'modification.user',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user'
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'areas',
        localField: 'modification.updated',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'updated'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        modification: {
          user: {
            $arrayElemAt: ['$user', 0]
          },
          date: 1,
          updated: {
            $map: {
              input: '$modification.updated',
              as: 'item',
              in: {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                    from: {
                      $arrayElemAt: ['$updated', 0]
                    },
                    to: {
                      $arrayElemAt: ['$updated', 1]
                    }
                  },
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $eq: ['$$item', '$$from._id']
                      },
                      '$$from.name',
                      {
                        $cond: [
                          {
                            $eq: ['$$item', '$$to._id']
                          },
                          '$$to.name',
                          '$$item'
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        'modification.date': 1
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        modification: {
          date: 1,
          user: {
            name: 1,
            last_name: 1
          },
          updated: 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        modification: {
          $push: '$modification'
        }
      }
    }
]);

// USAMOS la agregación, ejecutando el método 'exec()'

aggregateByArea.exec((err: any, results: any) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
    }
    if(!results.length) { // el método aggregate devuelve un array con los resultados
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Not found'});
    }
    return res.status(200).json({results});
});
```

Puede ser un poco intimidante al principio, sin embargo es muy sencillo una vez que entendemos los conceptos de [*etapas*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) (*stages*) y [*tubería*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/index.html#aggregation-pipeline) (*pipeline*), como parte del proceso de Agregación de MongoDB.

De esta forma se devuelven los documentos en un `Array` tal como los deseas según el requerimiento de tu pregunta.

## RESPUESTA LARGA

**EXPLICACIÓN DE LA RESPUESTA CORTA**

Me opongo a respuestas tipo: *copia y pega esta solución*, por ello daré la explicación del método de agregación por etapas, para que se entienda lo que estamos haciendo.

**Etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match):**

La primera etapa recibe como parámetro el `id` del documento de usuario sobre el que deseamos realizar el proceso de Agregación. Como nota, la [API de agregación de Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) no realiza el `cast` de los tipos de datos durante la canalización de las etapas, es por ello que usaremos la conversión del tipo `String` devuelto por `req.params.id` al tipo `ObjectId` de Mongo.

Esta etapa, devuelve el documento cuyo campo `_id` coincida con el que valor que hemos pasado como parámetro. Se podría equiparar al método `findById(id)`.

```
_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) //<= se realiza la conversión usando mongoose.Types.ObjectId(str)
```

**Etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):**

En esta etapa crearemos la estructura básica del documento que deseamos como resultado. En este caso estoy tomando como referencia lo que planteas en tu pregunta.

Siendo el campo `modification` de tipo `Array`, para poder trabajar con el mismo usaremos el operador [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html), el cual itera sobre cada elemento de nuestro array.

Por cada elemento del array, voy a indicarle los campos que deseo que sean devueltos. Así, si deseo el campo `user`, debo indicarlo como:

```
'user': '$$mod.user',
```

En esta etapa, lo crucial es lo que hacemos con el campo `updated`, el cual es un tipo `Array`.

Sobre dicho campo usaremos el operador `$map` y convertiremos cada `item` (que sea posible) en un tipo `ObjectId`. Para ello usaremos el operador [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html).

> **NOTA**
>
> El operador **`$convert`** sólo está disponible en MongoDB versión 4.0 o posterior.

Lo que haremos es intentar convertir cada valor de `updated` a un tipo ObjectId. Digo *intentar* porque no todos los valores de nuestro array son cadenas válidas para convertirlas a un tipo `ObjectId` de Mongo.

Tomando en cuenta que el campo `updated` contiene un valor similar al siguiente:

```
[ 'area', '5d144642416ada46385d01b8', '5d144681416ada46385d01b9', 'Área'];
```

Se observa claramente que el primer y el último elemento de nuestro array no son valores válidos en `String` para ser convertidos en `ObjectId`. Es por ello que usamos el atributo `onError` de nuestro operador `$convert`, el cual nos permite devolver un valor en caso de error durante la conversión:

```
$convert: {
    input: '$$item',   //<- Elemento a convertir
    to: 'objectId',    //<- Tipo al que será convertido
    onError: '$$item'  //<- Elemento a devolver en caso de error
}
```

Ahora el campo `updated` tendrá la siguiente estructura:

```
[ 'area', ObjectId('5d144642416ada46385d01b8'), ObjectId('5d144681416ada46385d01b9'), 'Área'];
```

> ¿Porqué hemos convertido los tipo `String` en tipo `ObjectId`?

La respuesta a esta pregunta viene dada en la etapa `$lookup`.

**Etapa [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html):**

Esta etapa nos facilitará las cosas a la hora de trabajar con los datos del array `modification`. Lo que hace esta etapa es crear un documento por cada elemento presente en nuestro array, y el campo `modification` se convierte en un tipo `document`.

Dado que es un poco difícil entender el proceso hasta que se ve el resultado, dejaré algunas imágenes que pueden aclarar un poco lo que ocurre:

Antes de realizar la etapa `$unwind` nuestra agregación se ve como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Aggregation Stage antes de realizar $unwind]

Podemos notar que hay un sólo documento que contiene todos los datos de modificación en el campo `modification`.

Al realizar la etapa de `$unwind`, el resultado será el siguiente:

[image: Aggregation Stage luego de realizar $unwind]

Ahora claramente podemos observar que se han creado 3 documentos (1 por cada elemento del campo `modification`), además, el campo `modification` pasó de ser un tipo `Array` a ser un campo que contiene un documento.

Ahora podremos trabajar sin problemas sobre el campo `updated` de cada documento.

**Etapa [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html):**

En esta etapa lo que hacemos es algo parecido al *JOIN* de SQL. La idea es traer los datos de otra colección (aunque la misma no tenga una referencia directa con la que estamos procesando). Para ello debemos establecer el campo por el cual deseamos hacer la referencia.

Aquí cobra importancia la primera etapa de `$project` y la etapa de `$unwind`, ya que vamos a buscar datos de la colección `areas` usando como campo de referencia los valores `ObjectId` del campo `updated` (el cual es un tipo `Array`). Además, haremos una etapa `$lookup` adicional para traer los datos de la colección `users` (si entiendo bien el propósito del campo `modification`: se almacena el `_id` del usuario que realizó la modificación).

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'areas', // <= Colección desde donde se extrae la data
    localField: 'modification.updated',  // <= valor sobre el que se va a realizar el lookup
    foreignField: '_id', // <= Campo de la colección externa sobre el que se realizará el lookup
    as: 'updated' // <= Nombre del nuevo campo que contendrá los resultados del lookup
  }
}
```

Siendo que `modification.updated` es un campo de tipo `Array`, el proceso de `$lookup` se llevará a cabo sobre cada elemento de dicho `Array`, cada documento devuelto por `$lookup` será añadido a un `Array` llamado `updated` que es el nombre que le hemos pasado como valor al atributo `as`.

Un ejemplo de nuestro documento hasta este momento sería el siguiente:

[image: Documento luego de la etapa de $lookup]

Como se aprecia en la imagen (sólo se muestra el primer documento), se han añadido 2 campos: `user` y `updated`, ambos contienen documentos de las colecciones `users` y `areas` que corresponden a los `_id` sobre los que se ha hecho el `$lookup`. Para este ejemplo, el modelo `Area` es muy básico, solo contiene el campo `name`, nuestro modelo `User` también es básico para usarlo en este ejemplo.

**Segunda etapa `$project`**

Ahora que ya tenemos los datos que necesitamos, pasaremos a la siguiente etapa. En esta, vamos a construir lo que se convertirá en nuestro documento final.

Tal vez visualmente esta etapa es muy compleja, pero lo cierto es que los procesos que allí se realizan son muy sencillos.

En la primera parte de la etapa declaramos el campo `modification` e incluimos dentro del mismo los siguientes valores:

```
user: {
  $arrayElemAt: ['$user', 0]
}
```

Debemos recordar que el campo `user` agregado en la etapa anterior es un tipo `Array` que contiene los documentos encontrados al realizar la búsqueda sobre el campo `_id`. Es por ello que se usa el operador [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) al cual se le pasa como parámetro la ruta del `Array` (`$user`) y la posición del elemento que queremos obtener (en este caso el primer elemento). esto nos devolverá el documento que contiene los datos del usuario, algo equiparable al método [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) de Mongoose.

```
date: 1,
```

Esto indica que se incluirá el campo `date` que hemos venido agregando en cada etapa.

Por último, crearemos un campo llamado `updated` que contendrá los valores nuevos que hemos obtenido en la etapa de `$lookup`.

La construcción la haremos usando el operador `$map`, ya que el campo `updated` es de tipo `Array`.

El `Array` de entrada será el que hemos modificado en nuestra primera etapa de `$project`, el cual contiene la siguiente estructura:

```
['area', ObjectId('5d144642416ada46385d01b8'), ObjectId('5d144681416ada46385d01b9'), 'Área'];
```

Luego definiremos 2 variables:

```
from: { $arrayElemAt: ['$updated', 0]},
to: { $arrayElemAt: ['$updated', 1]}
```

Las mismas hacen referencia a los 2 documentos del campo `updated` que hemos creado durante la etapa de `$lookup`. La idea es comparar el valor de `ObjectId` del `Array` de origen con el valor de `ObjectId` del documento que hemos llenado de la colección `areas`.

Una vez establecidas nuestras variables realizaremos un retorno condicional, es decir, retornaremos un valor de acuerdo a si se cumple una condición o no. Para ello usaremos el operador [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html), usando la siguiente sintaxis:

```
{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }
```

Nuestra expresión booleana será:

```
{ $eq: ['$$item', '$$from._id']}
```

Donde `$$item` se refiere al valor del iterando de nuestro `Array` de entrada, y `$$from._id` será el valor del campo `_id` de nuestro primer elemento.

Si hay coincidencia devolvemos el valor de `$$from.name`, de lo contrario pasamos a la siguiente parte del condicional, donde realizaremos nuevamente una operación de comparación condicional para determinar si se devuelve el valor de `$$to.name` o simplemente devolvemos el valor de `$item`.

Una vez realizadas todas estas tareas, el campo `updated` debe tener la siguiente estructura:

```
['area', 'Sistemas', 'Recursos Humanos', 'Área'];
```

Que es la estructura deseada.

> **Nota:** Se puede hacer la asignación de forma directa, ya que en teoría el orden en que aparecen es el mismo y la comparación sería innecesaria. Sin embargo, para este ejemplo he decidido realizar las cosas mostrando un poco las capacidades que tenemos al usar un método de agregación. Aunque eso significa escribir un poco más de código.

**Etapa [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html):**

Hasta ahora ya tenemos la estructura armada de nuestro documento, ahora vamos a ordenarla usando el campo `modification.date` en orden ascendente (fecha más antigua hacia la más reciente).

```
{ $sort: { 'modification.date': 1 }},
```

**Tercera etapa `$project`:**

En esta tercera y última etapa `$project`, vamos a sanitizar o sanear los datos que deseamos mostrar en el campo `user`. Hasta ahora se muestran todos los campos del documento, pero deseamos mostrar solamente los campos `_id`, `name` y `last_name`. Es por ello que escribimos lo siguiente:

```
user: {
  name: 1,
  last_name: 1
},
```

En donde le indicamos a MongoDB que deseamos sólo el campo `name` y el campo `last_name`. El campo `_id` siempre se incluirá a menos que escribamos explícitamente: `_id: 0`.

**Etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html):**

Esta será nuestra última etapa. Recordemos que durante la agregación separamos los documentos en tantos ítems como elementos tuviera el campo `modification`. Ahora es tiempo de reagrupar todos estos documentos, en uno solo y convertir nuevamente el campo `modification` en un `Array`, tal como aparece el documento original.

Dado que todos los documentos creados en la etapa `$unwind` corresponden al mismo `_id` de usuario, usaremos dicho campo como `_id` de nuestra agrupación:

```
{ $group: { _id: '$_id', modification: { $push: '$modification' }}}
```

En esta etapa le estamos diciendo a MongoDB que agrupe todos los documentos que contengan el mismo campo `_id`, y que en dicha agrupación, cree un campo llamado `modification` que será de tipo `Array` ya que usaremos el operador [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push), para insertar cada valor del campo `modification` de cada uno de los documentos que estamos agrupando.

Dado que todos los documentos tienen el mismo `_id`, el resultado será un documento único, que contiene un campo de tipo `Array` cuyos elementos se corresponden con los cambios realizados sobre el usuario, y donde hemos agregado los datos del usuario que realizó los cambios y además hemos cambiado los valores de `id` de área por el nombre del área.

Ejemplo de agregación **antes** de realizar la etapa de `$group`:

[image: Documento antes de la etapa de $group]

Se puede apreciar que la agregación devuelve varios documentos, todos tienen el mismo valor para el campo `_id`.

Ejemplo de agregación **después** de realizar la etapa de `$group`:

[image: Documento después de la etapa $group]

Ahora se aprecia que la agregación devuelve un solo documento donde el campo `modification` es un tipo `Array`, cuyos elementos se corresponden con cada modificación realizada sobre el usuario.

**RECOMENDACIONES FINALES**

Una de las recomendaciones que puedo hacerte es que escribas la agregación como un método del modelo. De esta forma, puedes usarlo desde cualquier otro método en que lo necesites y así no tienes que repetir nada de código, sólo la llamada.

Puedes consultar la documentación sobre [métodos de instancia](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) de Mongoose, para mayor información, o consultar la API de mongoose sobre métodos de `Schema`.

Por ejemplo podrías hacer lo siguiente en tu modelo:

**user.model.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import validator from 'mongoose-unique-validator'

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // Defines tu modelo
});

UserSchema.methods = {
  getModByArea: function(id) {
    return this.model('User').aggregate([
      // aquí va el documento de agregación que usamos al principio.
      // Recuerda siempre que el documento de agregación va dentro de un array
      // por ello se abre el método usando 'aggregate(['
    ]);
  }
}
```

Luego, para usar la agregación puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
UserChangesRoute.get( '/:id', ( req: Request, res: Response ) => {
  const id:String = req.params.id;
  User.findById(id, (error,user) => { //realizamos la búsqueda en la DB para asegurarnos que el usuario existe
    if(error) {
      return res.status(500).json({error: error.message});
    }
    if(!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Not found'});
    }
    const modificationByArea = user.getModByArea(user._id); // <- Se llama al método de la instancia
    getModByArea.exec((err, results) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
      }
      return res.status(200).json({results});
    });
  });
});
```

De esta forma tienes todo centralizado en el modelo `User`. Además, así como has escrito una agregación para `area`, puedes escribirla para `roles` y `jefes`, etc. Siempre que el valor de `update` cumpla el formato especificado. Sólo cambias el valor de la colección sobre la que harás el `$lookup`.

Incluso puedes hacer una agregación que te devuelva todo, haciendo varias etapas `$lookup`, una por cada colección sobre la que desees obtener la información.

Por ejemplo:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'areas',
    localField: 'modification.updated',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'areas'
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'roles',
    localField: 'modification.updated',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'roles'
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'jefes',
    localField: 'modification.updated',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'jefes'
  }
}
```

Como puedes ver, he encadenado varias etapas `$lookup`, cada una apunta a una colección diferente, luego debes ir refactorizando el código según sea necesario.

La ventaja de usar la agregación sobre lo que intentabas hacer (realizando una consulta a la DB por cada `id` en el campo `updated`), es que la agregación implica una sola llamada a la base de datos, todos los procesos se realizan del lado del motor de base de datos, y en teoría serán más rápidos que realizar el proceso manualmente desde tu aplicación.

Imagina que un usuario tiene 10 (por decir pocas) entradas en el campo de modificaciones, eso significa, que debes realizar 20 solicitudes (2 por cada entrada) a la base de datos para obtener la información sobre el nombre del campo asociado al `id` de cada entrada. Eso no es para nada práctico, sin contar el encadenamiento que debes hacer, o el uso de una función `async` para poder usar `await` con las llamadas a la BD.

Espero que esto sea una solución a tu problema y te ayude a entender un poco el mundo de las agregaciones.

Comment: Wow, te tomaste todo el tiempo del mundo, un verdadero amante de Mongo. Una respuesta muy completa, muy detallada. Hay muchas preguntas, pero ya me tocará a mi investigar con la literatura que has linkeado. De nuevo agradezco tu respuesta tan completa.